# Disable password expiration in asp.net membership provider

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-membership

My site currently uses Asp Membership Provider for Login. For the Admin of my site, the password expires every 30 days, and when he tries to login, it redirects him to password reset page. I need to disable or lengthen the time required for the admin to reset the password.

How should I disable password expiration for admin. Did try couple of attributes in web.config MembershipProvider but to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, yeah I have this site already built that customzies asp membership provider functionality somewhat. I am yet unable to figure out how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, password expiration is not a feature of the SqlMembershipProvider.  If you're using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, I'd assume you can change it in ActiveDirectory.

Perhaps the method used in this article has been employed?

https://web.archive.org/web/20211020153411/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070809-1.aspx